# Identifier Expected Confusion

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I am working on a project and I'm getting an identifier error. I'm not sure how to fix this. It is on the 5th line. Thanks for the help! :)

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void clickFunction (RelativeLayout) {
        RelativeLayout theRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.backgroundfirst);
        theRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundsecond);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void clickFunction (RelativeLayout)
```

This is an invalid method signature, you only define the type of the parameter, you also have to define its name:

```
public void clickFunction (RelativeLayout relativeLayout)
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score -1):

The argument to the function in line 5 does not have a name. A function declaration has to look like this:

```
public void clickFunction (RelativeLayout layout) {...}
```

Notice the name of the argument.